# What does sowieso mean?

Tags: translation, german-to-english

I was watching a German show, and they kept using the word **sowieso?** Can someone explain to me what it means?

Comment: „sowieso“ means „ohnehin“.

Comment: Shouldn't we keep a question with 7k views open?

Comment: @Robert No, if it does not conform to our rules, we shouldn’t. You are of course welcome to edit it according to our rules.

Answer (score 9):

The most literal translation for the adverb *sowieso* is

> one way or the other

Normally, the English *anyway* translates the word well.

Some examples:

> "Ich kann es sowieso nicht verhindern."
>
> "I can't prevent it anyway."

Sometimes it's used as informal answer and means *of course*:

> "Kommst du morgen zur Feier?" - "Sowieso!"

Also, as mentioned in a comment to this answer, there is another special meaning, for example:

> "Ein Herr Sowieso hat angerufen."

In this case *Sowieso* is a placeholder for a name that the person getting the phone call didn't remember or understand.

Comment: If you want to get a more detailed description of which "anyway" it is you can check out the article I have written about "eh"... both words are synonyms...http://yourdailygerman.wordpress.com/2013/08/23/meaning-eh/

Answer (score 2):

*sowieso* is the same as *anyway*, *in any case* or *anyhow*. I am a native German speaker.

Examples:

> Das brauchst du ihm nicht zu sagen, das weiß er sowieso schon. (You don't need to tell him, he knows it already.)
>
> Du kannst es mir mitgeben, ich gehe sowieso dahin. (you can give that to me, i will go there anyway.)